# Every time I open a SLN, Visual Studio loses my TFS connection

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2019

We have our documentation and so on in a TFS repo and use VS to manage this through Source Control Explorer. Our code is in a Git repo on the same server, in fact it's hosted as part of the same Azure Devops as TFS.

I used VS to get the source code from git since I hadn't got a git client installed at the time, and now any time I open a SLN, VS sets the git repo as my source-control. If I switch back to TFS, it closes any open solutions. So I cannot have code open while browsing our documentation source control.

I cannot see any way to remove the git repo and start over. I don't want to use VS for Git, I just want to be able to open individual projects solutions.

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot to illustrate your process? This will help people understand your issue more intuitively.

Comment: Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue?